# Proving the formula for distance between a point and a parametric line

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

Let $l$ be a line in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with parametric equation $\alpha(t) = a + t\boldsymbol{v}$ and $p$ an arbitrary point.

Show that the (shortest) distance between $p$ and $l$ is given by

$$d = \frac{||(\boldsymbol{p - a}) \times \boldsymbol{v}||}{||\boldsymbol{v}||}$$

I've attempted to render an image corresponding to the problem, where $Q$ is the point at the foot of a perpendicular dropped from $P$ to $l$. (Please excuse capital $P$ instead of $p$ in the drawing).

[image]

By the definition of $sin$ we have $d = \sin\theta||p - a||.$ But from there, I don't see why the cross product of $||p - a||$ with $\boldsymbol{v}$ divided by $||\boldsymbol{v}||$ would be related to $d$ or how it would get rid of the $\sin\theta$.

By the right hand rule, wouldn't the cross product of $p - a$ and $\boldsymbol{v}$ be sticking "out" in a direction unrelated to $d$?

Thank you.

Comment: Think of the numerator in the formula for $d$ as the area of a parallelogram and the denominator of $d$ as the length of the parallelogram's base.

Answer (score 3):

The shortest vector between the line and the point will be orthogonal to $v$. We need to find the $t$ to get this vector.

Given $\alpha(t)=a+tv$ and $p$ we want to find:

$$t: \langle p - a-tv,v \rangle = 0 \implies p\cdot v - a\cdot v-t|v|^2 = 0  \implies t=\frac{p\cdot v -a\cdot v}{|v|^2} = \frac{(p-a)\cdot v}{|v|^2}$$

Recognizing that $d(t)=|p-a-tv|$ we get:

$$d(t) = \left| p-a - \frac{(p-a)\cdot v}{|v|^2}v \right| = \left| p-a - \frac{(p-a)\cdot v}{|v|}\frac{v}{|v|} \right|$$

Let $\hat v := \frac{v}{|v|}$ to simplify to:

$$d(t) =  \left| (p-a) - [(p-a)\cdot \hat v] \hat v \right|=|(p-a)\times \hat v|=\frac{|(p-a)\times v|}{|v|}$$

In words, we are removing the portion of the vector $p-a$ in the same direction as the line $\alpha(t)$ and finding the length of the remaining portion of $p-a$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Upvoting because it looks right. Not marking as accepted only because I have a hard time following every single step as a noob to this topic.

Comment: @RTF What part is hard to follow? Which step do you have questions about?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to be a bit gauche and answer my own question since it's based on the only explanation so far I've been able to follow completely.

If there are any mistakes in what follows, please let me know and I will correct. (Credit to https://www.nagwa.com/en/explainers/939127418581/)

Forget about point $Q$ and instead focus on vector $p - a$ and directional vector $\boldsymbol{v}$.

[image]

Note that the area of the parallelogram formed by $(p-a)$ and $\boldsymbol{v}$ is $A = ||(p-a) \times \boldsymbol{v} ||$

On the other hand, the area of the parallelogram is its base times it height. Here, the base is $||\boldsymbol{v}||$ and the height is $d$. Thus, we have

$$A = ||(p-a) \times \boldsymbol{v} || = ||\boldsymbol{v}||(d) \Longrightarrow d = \frac{||(p-a) \times \boldsymbol{v} ||}{||\boldsymbol{v}||}$$

Comment: Yes, this works too :-) It is based on the same idea — the “height” here is a line perpendicular to $v$ and interesting $p$. It’s actually a nice, geometric way to get at it.